# Save names of all new document files to a txt document with log

Tags: windows-explorer, pdf, file-management, notepad

I need to keep a concise record of all the pdf files I save at work.

Is there a utility or script I can run, preferably without installing (stand-alone exe?) that will generate a .txt file or the like of all the file names I save, with a time/date stamp?

If it helps, most of them are printed and saved using the Adobe PDF print dialog. I also always save them to the same folder. (This is on a network drive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a utility I can run, preferably without installing (stand-alone
>   exe?) that will generate a .txt file or the like of all the file names I
>   save, with a time/date stamp?

No need to install anything for this.

```
[start], run, cmd, 
cd to folder with tthe PDFs
dir *.pdf > file.txt
```

All of which you can put into a batch file.

Note that this will create a list of all the files as asking in the question. Your title however asks a different question.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with batch script format, could you provide a template?

Comment: To make it clearer, fire up a command prompt. Use the cd command to navigate to the path of your pdf files, then type dir/s *.pdf > filelist.txt

Comment: I got it to work with a tip from a coworker; she had me `(ctrl+shift)right-click inside the directory>Open command Window Here` which does the cd automatically. I then just input `dir > LIst.txt` and presto, we have a nice log file, but it doesn't work usiing `cd` from a blank slate CMD window to the directory. It doesn't give errors, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: OK, read an article and realized I can't cd into a drive `s` in this case I have to type `s:` and get a `S:\` prompt, and type `cd \Directory1\Directory1a` which yields `S:\DIrectory1\Directorya>` to which I add `dir> *.pdf > file.txt` which works wonderfully, just not sure how the bat script is going to be formatted.

Comment: A bit late to the party, but yes. DOS and windows `cd` is weird in that you need to use `cd /s` to change a drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the dir command to a file list like this:

```
dir>directory_content.txt
```

You could use the Windows scheduler to run this command at the end of each day. If you want to get fancy, you create a batch file that will create the txt file name based on current day and run that batch each day

Comment: I am getting the error 'The sysem cannot find the path specified'. I should have clarified, this is on a network drive.

Comment: The example isn't very good, you need to do something along the lines of what @hennes said

Comment: Try​ to use that command as `cmd.exe /c "dir /s folder_name\*.PDF"`